# How do I extend the ribbon cable in the photo?

Tags: ribbon-cable

[image]

It is a electronic cam lock for lockers. I want the dial pad to be further away from the locking mechanism.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cut the wires and solder longer ones.

Comment: So I just have to cut the wire, strip it, and solder on the new wire? Also do you know what kind of ribbon cable I would need? I think it has 7 pins, but I not familiar with these cables

Comment: Pretty much. I would also add heat-shrinked insulation. But how long do you want this cable be? BTW, this is not ribbon. These are individual wires, no?

Comment: Heat shrinked insulation! I’ve never heard of it, I’ll look it up! Thank you! I want it to be about 2 1/2 feet long. But I can make it shorter

Comment: If you can identify the connectors then you may be able to find a ready-made cable assembly - something like [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0151360706/WM16385-ND/6796546).

Answer (score 1):

Don't even solder the wire extensions, solder makes stranded wire brittle.

Strip 3cm ends.

Twist the two ends together tightly and clip excess.

Lay the twisted end against the wire.

Slip on a length of heat-shrink tubing.

Use cigarette lighter to shrink the tubing.

Add another layer of tubing if you like.

Practice the technique on scrap wire and pull on it afterward to verify just how strong the connection is.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the diagram! So I cut the socket off of the wires coming from either the locking mechanism or keypad, and then attach the extension ribbon and then plug that socket into either the locking part or keypad?

Comment: i will leave it to you to do some thinking and figure out what you have to do to make the cable longer  ..... draw it on paper if you have to

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a JST ZH series (but it's difficult to tell without a scale). There are not, as far as i know, cable mount JST ZH male connectors so you can't simply buy an extension. If you don't want to extend the individual wires you could connect two JST ZH male connectors back to back, and buy a longer JST ZH female to female cable.

Comment: I was thinking of buying this version. I have been looking for a reputable store to buy something like this  ( Electronic Cabinet Lock Kit Set, Keyless Digital Keypad Door Lock with Password Entry https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DGRJ928/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_r67nCbGC292CY) from but I’ve had no luck so far.

Comment: Looking at that I'd be worried that the decision to open the door is being made in the tamper-able keypad, rather than the box on the secure side of the door.  The standard for entry keypads and card readers is weigand, which is very easy to extend. You might be able to find some parts (a controller, a solenoid and a keypad) cheaply.

Comment: Luckily I don’t really need it to be very secure. I’m just building a prototype. I’m pretty new to any kind of electronic tinkering but I might try building one. But if I can avoid buy something already made that would be best. I saw this Giantree IP65 Weigand 26 Access Control System Door Keypad Locks Touch Keypad Door Lock https://www.amazon.com/dp/B076Q5L945/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_xh9nCbN0Q7NJX and I like that the ribbons are long, but I don’t see a lock and there aren’t any reviews. Thank you for your input btw